# Running setup.py install for lz4 ... error

Tags: python, lz4, salesforce-einstein

I am trying to do `pip install SalesforceEinsteinAnalytics` over my virtual environment referring the link `https://github.com/ahilgenkamp/SalesforceEinsteinAnalytics`

But while running it over powershell, I am getting an error as `Running setup.py install for lz4 ... error. SalesforceEinsteinAnalytics library has a dependency lz4, which is not getting installed. [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30sDE.png)

Help

Comment: The error asks you to install install >=Visual C++ 14.0

Comment: Please post the actual error message, not an image of it.

Comment: Please could you guide me as to how can I install >=Visual C++ 14.0 but what if someone else is using the code and facing the same error on there computer?

Comment: @Sören I am getting an error as "Installing collected packages: lz4, keyring, idna, charset-normalizer, unidecode, unicodecsv, requests, pandas, datetime, browser-cookie3, SalesforceEinsteinAnalytics
    Running setup.py install for lz4 ... error"

Comment: Please post the actual error message **as part of your question**, not as a comment. The solution to your problem is in the [...] part.